# wp3 custom post types rss

Tags: custom-post-types, rss, feed

From what I've found online, getting an rss feed for a custom post type is as simple as:

```
http://mywebsite.com/feed/?post_type=custom_type
```

Well I have tried it with no success as it just returns the default feed. However I can get this to work on the website just fine with

```
http://mywebsite.com/?post_type=custom_type
```

So why does it work for the html but not the rss feed? Please advise.

** EDIT **

I ended up adding this to my theme's functions.php:

```
function myfeed_request($qv) {
    if (isset($qv['feed']) && isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        //$qv['post_type'] = get_post_types();
        $qv['post_type'] = explode(',', $_GET['post_type']);
    }

    return $qv;
}
add_filter('request', 'myfeed_request');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to include post types to your feed:

```
function myfeed_request($qv) {
   if (isset($qv['feed']))
   $qv['post_type'] = get_post_types();
   return $qv;
}
add_filter('request', 'myfeed_request');
```

Just add it to your functions.php. This should help.

[Source](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-types?replies=11).

Comment: I modified a line of your code and viola. See my edit.